# Trying to pull the Redirect URL from a given URL in Google Sheets, with only the Redirect URL printed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a list of URLs in Google Sheets which all redirect when clicked on. I had been manually going through and clicking the URLs, copying the Redirect URL, and then pasting it into a new column of the spreadsheet. Problem is there thousands, and I want to be more efficient. Currently I have this code:

```
function getRedirects(url) {
  var params = {
    'followRedirects': false,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var followedUrls = [url];

  while (true) {
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    if (res.getResponseCode() < 300 || res.getResponseCode() > 399) {
      return followedUrls;
    }
    var url = res.getHeaders()['Location'];
    followedUrls.push(url);
  }
}
```

The problem is, this code prints both the original URL as well as the Redirect URL. Is there any way to have it print ONLY the Redirect URL? I am hoping to print only the Redirect URL so that I can drag the function =getRedirects(url) down the column on the spreadsheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: using followedUrls.shift(); removes the Redirect URL but keeps the original URL, appreciate the feedback though

Comment: I will take a look, thank you! For now, I just opened a new sheet and transposed my data to then clean it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom function will return an array of URLs that let you see the full redirect flow, which may contain multiple redirects. That is useful functionality, so you may want to keep your current `getRedirects()` function as is, and create another function that returns just the final redirect destination. Try this:

```js
function getFinalRedirect(url) {
  return getRedirects(url).pop();
}
```

Then, in your spreadsheet formulas, use `=getFinalRedirect(A2)` instead of `=getRedirects(A2)`.

Comment: Ahhh this is perfect! The above answer was very helpful, but in instances of multiple redirects this will be most efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The line `var followedUrls = [url];` will add the original URL as the first array value of `followedUrls` because of the `url` parameter was added on its creation. Thus, when you run your custom function, for example getRedirects(A1), the followedUrls array will return the original URL and then the redirected URL on your sheet.

**Additional recommendation:**

Instead using the reverse shift() method, you can also just remove `url` parameter on your declaration of the `var followedUrls = [];`

Comment: Its.... beautiful :') thank you for the recommendation and explanation!